# Is it possible to see silverlight based pages without the silverlight plug in

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have an asp.net application in which I have built few silverlight based pages. 
The problem is that most of our users do not have install priviledges on their system and they cannot install Silverlight plug-in themselves. Our IT Support will not agree installing Silverlight on all 4000 machines.

Is their something we can do so that users may not be asked to install the Silverlight plug-in and still the Silverlight pages being displayed to them.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware no it's not possible. Suggest reworking the few pages if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client cannot render the silverlight, then it just renders whatever is inside of the object tag. In your case, instead of a "get silverlight" link, this could be a non interactive version of your page.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to not use Silverlight for browsers that don't have the Silverlight plugin. There are ways to detect Silverlight server-side (although they're [mostly hacks](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/59318/149253.aspx)). If you detect Silverlight, push down a Silverlight-enabled page. If you do not detect Silverlight, push down plain HTML and/or AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need either Silverlight on Windows or Mac, or Moonlight on Linux to run Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that your Silverlight pages are simple, IE will render a XAML page.  Of course, this will only work with the simplest content, and it would be non-compiled xaml, like an HTML page.  If you save the following example as "whatever.xaml" and browse to it, it will render in IE.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    >    
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Orange">
        <TextBlock>Alex</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```